# Accessing static C functions in Python

Tags: python, c, function, static, swig

How can I access static function in Python from C using SWIG? For example:

```
static int foo(int a, int b);
```

The C code can't be changed.

Comment: I'm confused how this would work - if a function is static in C it can't be accessed in another translation unit in the same C program. The only way it's possible is if the function definition is in a headerfile somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The only way this is really possible is if either

1. You have the declaration and definition inside a header file
2. You have a way of getting a function pointer
3. Some crazy crazy hackery
4. You have the source of the whole program available

For #1 I put together an example header file we might be working with:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <stdio.h>

static int foo(int a, int b) {
  return printf("Frobination: %d-%d\n",a,b);
}

#endif
```

It's a little bit weird to be doing that inside of a header file though, but not impossible. In that case we can wrap it as normal with:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%include "test.h"
```

And run it as:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:16:07) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test
>>> test.foo(1,2)
Frobination: 1-2
17
>>>
```

with the caveat that it is of course a local version of the static function being used here just as normal when there are multiple translation units and static functions.

For #2 we might have the header file:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

typedef int (*fptr)(int a, int b);

extern fptr foo;

#endif
```

And an implementation of that as:

```
#include "test.h"
#include <stdio.h>

static int foo_impl(int a, int b) {
  return printf("Frobination: %d-%d\n",a,b);
}

fptr foo = foo_impl;
```

Which we can then wrap with:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

int foo(int a, int b);
```

Where we lied to SWIG and claimed that foo wasn't a function pointer, but it works and is perfectly legal because all the generated code is valid.

For #3 we could in theory, by various platform specific non-portable trickery extract the address the static function lives at into a function pointer, but that's fragile and all round a bad idea.

For #4 if you have the source available then you're home free.